# Cannot get JLabel to display JTextField Input

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield

I have my ProfileInput class to store a JTextField input from a Dialog box. Then I transfer that to the setter and getter methods. From there I am calling the setter and getter methods in my AppFrame class.

The the problem that I am having is when I want the input to be displayed as a JLabel on the GUI nothing is showing up. I have no errors that are displayed when I run the code either. Any ideas as to what I have done wrong.

Please note that I am new to Java and am trying to learn. Any ideas/help to improve anything is also great.

ProfileInput Class

```
package GUI;

//Library imports
import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class ProfileInput extends Dialog {


    //array for the active drop down box
    String[] activeLabels = {"Select One", "Not Active", "Slightly Active", "Active", "Very Active"};

    public String firstNameString;


    //intilizing aspects used in the user profile dialog box
    JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
    JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save");
    JLabel firstName = new JLabel("First Name: ");
    JLabel lastName = new JLabel("Last Name: ");
    JLabel age = new JLabel("Age: ");
    JLabel weight = new JLabel("Weight: ");
    JLabel height = new JLabel("Height: ");
    JLabel weightGoal = new JLabel("Weight Goal: ");
    JLabel activeLevel = new JLabel("Active Level: ");
    JLabel completion = new JLabel("Completion By: ");
    JTextField firstNameInput = new JTextField();
    JTextField lastNameInput = new JTextField(); 
    JTextField ageInput = new JTextField();
    JTextField weightInput = new JTextField();
    JTextField heightInputFeet = new JTextField();
    JTextField heightInputInches = new JTextField();
    JTextField weightGoalInput = new JTextField();
    JComboBox activeCombo = new JComboBox(activeLabels);
    JTextField completionInput = new JTextField();


    //setup of the dialog panel
    public ProfileInput(Frame parent) {

        super(parent,true);
        userProfileInput();
        setSize(315, 380);
        setTitle("Profile Creator");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

    public void userProfileInput() {

        //sets up the main panel for the dialog box (only panel to add to)
        Panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1,1,1,1));
        Panel.setLayout(null);


        //sets the location of the aspects inside the panel
        firstName.setBounds(35, 15, 150, 20);
        lastName.setBounds(35, 50, 150, 20);
        firstNameInput.setBounds(115, 15, 150, 20);
        lastNameInput.setBounds(115, 50, 150, 20);
        age.setBounds(35, 85, 120, 20);
        ageInput.setBounds(115, 85, 150, 20);
        weight.setBounds(35, 115, 150, 20 );
        weightInput.setBounds(115, 115, 150, 20);
        height.setBounds(35, 150, 150, 20);
        heightInputFeet.setBounds(115, 150, 72, 20);
        heightInputInches.setBounds(193, 150, 72, 20);
        weightGoal.setBounds(35, 185, 150, 20);
        weightGoalInput.setBounds(115, 185, 150, 20);
        activeLevel.setBounds(35, 220, 150, 20);
        activeCombo.setBounds(115,220, 150, 20);
        completion.setBounds(35, 255, 150, 20);
        completionInput.setBounds(130, 255, 120, 20);       
        saveButton.setBounds(135, 310, 65, 20);


        saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                //converts the inputs to a string
                firstNameString = firstNameInput.getText();


                System.out.println(firstNameString);

            }
        });



        //adds the items to the main panel on the dialog box
        Panel.add(firstName, null);
        Panel.add(lastName, null);
        Panel.add(firstNameInput, null);
        Panel.add(lastNameInput, null);
        Panel.add(age, null);
        Panel.add(ageInput, null);
        Panel.add(weight, null);
        Panel.add(weightInput, null);
        Panel.add(height, null);
        Panel.add(heightInputFeet, null);
        Panel.add(heightInputInches, null);
        Panel.add(weightGoal, null);
        Panel.add(weightGoalInput, null); 
        Panel.add(activeLevel, null);
        Panel.add(activeCombo, null);
        Panel.add(completion, null);
        Panel.add(completionInput, null);
        Panel.add(saveButton, null);


        //adds the panel to the dialog frame
        add(Panel);

    }//end of userProfileInput method


    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstNameString;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstNameString) {
        this.firstNameString = firstNameString;
    }

}
```

AppFrame Class

```
 public class AppFrame extends JFrame {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        ProfileInput profileInput = new ProfileInput(null);
        String firstNameTest = profileInput.getFirstName();

        /**
         * Starts the frame from AppFrame method below.
         * 
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            new AppFrame().setVisible(true);

        }//end of main Method


        /**
         * 
         * 
         */
        private AppFrame() {        

            //Initialization of panels and bars used in the main app
            JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
            JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
            JPanel profileInfo = new JPanel();

            //aspects used in the left toolbar panel
            JToolBar toolBarPanel = new JToolBar();
            JButton bloodPressureTool = new JButton();
            JButton heartRateTool = new JButton();
            JButton weightTool = new JButton();
            JButton bmiTool = new JButton();
            JButton medicationTool = new JButton();
            JButton appointmentTool = new JButton();
            JButton noteTool = new JButton();
            JButton profileTool = new JButton();
            Border etched = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder();
            Icon bloodPIcon = new ImageIcon("/Users/BrandonGrow/git/Health-Application/src/Icons/BloodPressure.png");
            Icon heartRateIcon = new ImageIcon("/Users/BrandonGrow/git/Health-Application/src/Icons/HeartRate.png");
            Icon weightIcon = new ImageIcon("/Users/BrandonGrow/git/Health-Application/src/Icons/Weight.png");
            Icon bmiIcon = new ImageIcon("/Users/BrandonGrow/git/Health-Application/src/Icons/BMI.png");
            Icon medicationIcon = new ImageIcon("/Users/BrandonGrow/git/Health-Application/src/Icons/Medications.png");
            Icon appointmentIcon = new ImageIcon("/Users/BrandonGrow/git/Health-Application/src/Icons/DoctorAppointment.png");
            Icon noteIcon = new ImageIcon("/Users/BrandonGrow/git/Health-Application/src/Icons/Notes.png");
            Icon profileIcon = new ImageIcon("/Users/BrandonGrow/git/Health-Application/src/Icons/Profile.png");


            //aspects of the user profile panel 
            JLabel firstName = new JLabel("First Name: ");
            JLabel lastName = new JLabel("Last Name: ");
            JLabel height = new JLabel("Height: ");
            JLabel weight = new JLabel("Weight: ");
            JLabel age = new JLabel("Age: ");
            JLabel weightGoal = new JLabel("Weight Goal: ");
            JLabel activeLevel = new JLabel("Active Level: ");
            JLabel completion = new JLabel("Completion Date: ");


            //Menu Bar Headers
            JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
            JMenu go = new JMenu("Go");
            JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");


            //file drop down
            JMenuItem newEntry = new JMenuItem("Profile Creator");
            JMenuItem exportReport = new JMenuItem("Export Report");
            JMenuItem exportNotes = new JMenuItem("Export Notes");
            JMenuItem preferences = new JMenuItem("Preferences");
            JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
            file.add(newEntry);
            file.addSeparator();
            file.add(exportReport);
            file.addSeparator();
            file.add(exportNotes);
            file.addSeparator();
            file.add(preferences);
            file.addSeparator();
            file.add(exit);


            //action used when the user presses the enter profile input button
            newEntry.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    profileInput.setVisible(true);

                }
            });


            //allows for the program to exit when exit is clicked
            exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        exitDialog();
                }
            });


            //go drop down
            JMenuItem bloodPressure = new JMenuItem("Blood Pressure");
            JMenuItem heartRate = new JMenuItem("Heart Rate");
            JMenuItem medication = new JMenuItem("Medication");
            JMenuItem weightDisplay = new JMenuItem("Weight");
            JMenuItem bmi = new JMenuItem("BMI");
            JMenuItem docAppoints = new JMenuItem("Doctor's Appointments");
            JMenuItem notes = new JMenuItem("Notes");
            JMenuItem resources = new JMenuItem("Profile");
            go.add(bloodPressure);
            go.addSeparator();
            go.add(heartRate);
            go.addSeparator();
            go.add(medication);
            go.addSeparator();
            go.add(weight);
            go.addSeparator();
            go.add(bmi);
            go.addSeparator();
            go.add(docAppoints);
            go.addSeparator();
            go.add(notes);
            go.addSeparator();
            go.add(resources);


            //help drop down
            JMenuItem usersGuide = new JMenuItem("Users Guide");
            JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About Personal Health Application");
            help.add(usersGuide);
            help.addSeparator();
            help.add(about);


            //adds Items to Frame
            menuBar.add(file);
            menuBar.add(go);
            menuBar.add(help);
            setJMenuBar(menuBar);


            //Panel that allows for all GUI to be ad added here
            contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1,1,1,1));
            contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            contentPane.add(toolBarPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
            contentPane.add(rightPanel);


            //stores the buttons for application (left)
            toolBarPanel.setOrientation(JToolBar.VERTICAL);
            toolBarPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
            toolBarPanel.setFloatable(false);;
            toolBarPanel.setBorder(etched);


            //sets the large panel on the right side of the frame.
            rightPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            rightPanel.setBorder(etched);
            rightPanel.setLayout(null);
            rightPanel.add(profileInfo, null);


            //adds the user profile info to the main screen
            profileInfo.setBounds(0, 0, 1104, 100);
            profileInfo.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            profileInfo.setLayout(null);
            profileInfo.setBorder(etched);

            firstName.setBounds(80, 10, 80, 20);
            firstName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 11));
            lastName.setBounds(80, 50, 80, 20);
            lastName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 11));
            weightDisplay.setBounds(310, 10, 80, 20);
            weightDisplay.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 11));
            height.setBounds(330, 50, 80, 20);
            height.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 11));
            age.setBounds(550, 10, 80, 20);
            age.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 11));
            weightGoal.setBounds(550, 50, 80, 20);
            weightGoal.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 11));
            activeLevel.setBounds(780, 10, 80, 20);
            activeLevel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 11));
            completion.setBounds(780, 50, 120, 20);
            completion.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 11));

            //test to see if first name displays
            JLabel firstNameInputTest = new JLabel(firstNameTest);
            firstNameInputTest.setBounds(160, 10, 80, 20);


            profileInfo.add(firstName);
            profileInfo.add(lastName);
            profileInfo.add(weightDisplay);
            profileInfo.add(height);
            profileInfo.add(age);
            profileInfo.add(weightGoal);
            profileInfo.add(completion);
            profileInfo.add(activeLevel);

//part of test to see of first name displays
            profileInfo.add(firstNameInputTest);


            //blood pressure button
            bloodPressureTool.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(90, 80));
            bloodPressureTool.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
            bloodPressureTool.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 10));
            bloodPressureTool.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 50));
            bloodPressureTool.setBorderPainted(false);
            bloodPressureTool.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            bloodPressureTool.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
            bloodPressureTool.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            bloodPressureTool.setText("Blood Pressure");
            bloodPressureTool.setOpaque(false);
            bloodPressureTool.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            bloodPressureTool.setSelected(true);
            bloodPressureTool.setIcon(bloodPIcon);


            //heart rate button
            heartRateTool.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(90, 80));
            heartRateTool.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
            heartRateTool.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 10));
            heartRateTool.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 50));
            heartRateTool.setBorderPainted(false);
            heartRateTool.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            heartRateTool.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
            heartRateTool.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            heartRateTool.setText("Heart Rate");
            heartRateTool.setOpaque(false);
            heartRateTool.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            heartRateTool.setSelected(true);
            heartRateTool.setIcon(heartRateIcon);


            //weight button
            weightTool.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(90, 80));
            weightTool.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
            weightTool.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 10));
            weightTool.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 50));
            weightTool.setBorderPainted(false);
            weightTool.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            weightTool.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
            weightTool.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            weightTool.setText("Weight");
            weightTool.setOpaque(false);
            weightTool.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            weightTool.setSelected(true);
            weightTool.setIcon(weightIcon);


            //BMI button
            bmiTool.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(90, 80));
            bmiTool.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
            bmiTool.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 10));
            bmiTool.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 50));
            bmiTool.setBorderPainted(false);
            bmiTool.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            bmiTool.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
            bmiTool.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            bmiTool.setText("BMI");
            bmiTool.setOpaque(false);
            bmiTool.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            bmiTool.setSelected(true);
            bmiTool.setIcon(bmiIcon);


            //medication button
            medicationTool.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(90, 80));
            medicationTool.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
            medicationTool.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 10));
            medicationTool.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 50));
            medicationTool.setBorderPainted(false);
            medicationTool.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            medicationTool.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
            medicationTool.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            medicationTool.setText("Medication");
            medicationTool.setOpaque(false);
            medicationTool.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            medicationTool.setSelected(true);
            medicationTool.setIcon(medicationIcon);


            //appointment button
            appointmentTool.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(90, 80));
            appointmentTool.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
            appointmentTool.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 10));
            appointmentTool.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 50));
            appointmentTool.setBorderPainted(false);
            appointmentTool.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            appointmentTool.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
            appointmentTool.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            appointmentTool.setText("Appointments");
            appointmentTool.setOpaque(false);
            appointmentTool.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            appointmentTool.setSelected(true);
            appointmentTool.setIcon(appointmentIcon);


            //note button
            noteTool.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(90, 80));
            noteTool.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
            noteTool.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 10));
            noteTool.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 50));
            noteTool.setBorderPainted(false);
            noteTool.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            noteTool.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
            noteTool.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            noteTool.setText("Notes");
            noteTool.setOpaque(false);
            noteTool.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            noteTool.setSelected(true);
            noteTool.setIcon(noteIcon);


            //profile button
            profileTool.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(90, 80));
            profileTool.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
            profileTool.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 10));
            profileTool.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 50));
            profileTool.setBorderPainted(false);
            profileTool.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            profileTool.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
            profileTool.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            profileTool.setText("Profile");
            profileTool.setOpaque(false);
            profileTool.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            profileTool.setSelected(true);
            profileTool.setIcon(profileIcon);


            //adding buttons to toolBarPanel
            toolBarPanel.add(bloodPressureTool);
            toolBarPanel.add(heartRateTool);
            toolBarPanel.add(weightTool);
            toolBarPanel.add(bmiTool);
            toolBarPanel.add(medicationTool);
            toolBarPanel.add(appointmentTool);
            toolBarPanel.add(noteTool);
            toolBarPanel.add(profileTool);


            //sets up the actual frame 
            setSize(1200,800);
            setResizable(false);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
            add(contentPane);


            //allows for the program to shut down by using x and then using the dialog
            addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    exitDialog();
                }
            });

        }//end of appFrame Method
```

Comment: Your `JLabel` `fistNameInputTest` is not showing up because the `String` `firstNameTest` is empty. You do call `getFirstName()` in your `AppFrame` class, but during the initialization, the only value `firstNameString` could be in your `ProfileInput` class is `null`. To fix this you will probably have to update the text of `firstNameInputTest` after the new profile is created.

Comment: Please see edits to answer. Please ask if any questions.

Answer (score 1):

You've got several problems with the above code, but most important, you're using a modeless dialog when you absolutely need to use a modal one. Since it is modeless, program flow in the calling code does not halt when the dialog is made visible, and so you're calling `getFirstName()` on the dialog *immediately* after it is opened, before it has been closed, and well before the user has had a chance to input any information whatsoever. A modal dialog on the other hand will freeze program flow in the calling code, and program flow will not resume until the dialog is no longer visible.

Problems and suggestions:

- First and foremost, make sure the dialog window is a ***modal*** dialog.
- But even before this, don't use Dialog, Panel and other AWT component classes, but rather use Swing classes -- JDialog, JPanel, etc.
- You can set the JDialog to be modal with either the proper constructor, passing in `ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL` as a parameter within the appropriate constructor (see the API), or you can set it via a method.
- Either way, make sure that it's set before setting the dialog visible.
- Do this, and when you query the state of the dialog, you can be assured that the user has at least had a chance to interact with the dialog before you try to extract information from it.
- Be sure to query the dialog and assign the results after setting it visible.

---

Edit, I see now that you're calling `String firstNameTest = profileInput.getFirstName();` even before setting the dialog visible, as if the firstNameTest String, which is obviously null at this stage, will magically update once the dialog has been visualized and dealt with, but sorry, there's no magic in Java, and fields will not update by themselves. Again, do not set the firstNameTest field at that point, but rather only after the dialog has been displayed and then dealt with.

---

Next we'll need to talk about `null` layouts and `setBounds`. You really don't want to go this route, trust me.

---

---

For example:

```
public class AppFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
    // !! the JLabel needs to be a field so it can be set in the ActionListener
    private JLabel firstNameInputTest = new JLabel(""); 
    private ProfileInput profileInput = null;  //!! let this start out as null
    // !! worthless code, get rid of
    // String firstNameTest = profileInput.getFirstName();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // .... etc
```

And the ActionListener where we create/display the dialog:

```
newEntry.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //!! create JDialog in a lazy fashion
        if (profileInput == null) {
            // create dialog, passing in the JFrame
            profileInput = new ProfileInput(AppFrame.this);
        }
        profileInput.setVisible(true); // display the *modal* dialog

        // program flow is frozen here until JDialog is no longer visible

        // query dialog for its contents
        String firstNameTxt = profileInput.getFirstName();
        // and use in GUI
        firstNameInputTest.setText(firstNameTxt);
    }
});
```

We don't want to declare the JLabel within a method or constructor since in doing so, it will not be visible throughout the class. So...

```
private AppFrame() { // ??? private ???

    // ..... 


    // test to see if first name displays
    // !! JLabel firstNameInputTest = new JLabel(firstNameTest);  // No!!!
```

Finally, a very simple example JDialog to demonstrate what I'm discussing:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ProfileInput extends JDialog {
    private JTextField firstNameField = new JTextField(10);

    public ProfileInput(JFrame frame) {
        // make it modal!
        super(frame, "Profile Input", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("Enter First Name:"));
        panel.add(firstNameField);
        panel.add(new JButton(new SubmitAction("Submit", KeyEvent.VK_S)));

        add(panel);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstNameField.getText();
    }

    private class SubmitAction extends AbstractAction {
        public SubmitAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ProfileInput.this.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That you very much for the info. I am definitely going to go through all of your thoughts. I really do appreciate your help with this. I want to learn the best practices. I will repost my code once I have it completed. Once again thats for the help!